# using angular $compile for string replacement

Tags: angularjs

```
endpointTemplate = "/api/endpoint?city={{city}}&state={{state}}&facility={{facility}}";
var model = angular.extend(scope.$new(), { city: 'Brooklyn', state: 'NY', facility: 'Facility 2' });
var compiled = $compile($('<a>', 
    {  
        //none of these work as i expect
        'ng-href': endpointTemplate,
        'test': endpointTemplate,
        'ng-bind': endpointTemplate 
    }));

var result = compiled(model);
```

I would like to get the value out like:

```
"/api/endpoint?city=Brooklyn&state=NY&facility=Facility 2"
```

But angular doesnt seem to leave the string "as-is" (except for the ng-bind attempt, which throws an error)

How can I make this work?

Comment: what do you mean by "**doesn't** seem to leave the string as-is"? Either "doesn't" is a typo, or I don't understand what you mean by "as-is"

Comment: I mean $compile doesn't replace the 3 placeholders in the string like I expect. It leaves the string with the placeholders ei "ng- href="/api/endpoint?city={{city}}..." instead of "ng-href="/api/endpoint?city=Brooklyn..."

Comment: It should replace... but only after a digest cycle

Comment: You can't have unescaped white-space in a URL. Moreover the `$compile` service is not responsible for interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that `result` will became interpolated once digest cycle is over. It is inappropriate use for `$compile` if all that's required is string interpolation, consider using [`$interpolate`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) instead, which

> is used by the HTML $compile service for data binding.

It should be something like this:

```
var model = { city: 'Brooklyn', state: 'NY', facility: 'Facility 2' };

var result = $interpolate($('<a>', ...)[0].outerHTML)(model);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer Im looking for. In fact, I was only using an element as a hack, I see I can use a string directly with $interpolate service ei, `$interpolate("/api/endpoint?city={{city}}")(model)` which is even better.

Comment: Is model data the same in both cases?